# Weird HTML behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, node.js

I have this page:

[image: Registration page.]

And, when I attempt to register with no fields, it correctly displays errors this way:

[image: Registration page with errors.]

However, while I was testing, I inserted one random character in each field, and pressed register and this is the screen I received (note that the error is correct, but that messes up my HTML):

[image: Messed up registration form]

Here is the AngularJS controller code:

```
app.controller('registerController', ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'cssInjector', function ($scope, $location, $http, cssInjector) {
    cssInjector.add('css/index.css');

    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.errors = [];

    $scope.home = function () {
        $location.path('/');
    };

    $scope.submit = function () {

        $http.post('/users', $scope.user).then( function (data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
        }, function (errors) {
            console.log('error');
            console.log(errors);

            $scope.errors = [];

            var errorsObject = errors.data.errors;

            for(var index in errorsObject) {
                console.log(index);
                $scope.errors[errorsObject[index].path] = errorsObject[index].message;
            }

            console.log($scope.errors);
        });

    };
}]);
```

Here is the request handled by Node.js:

```
app.post('/users', function (request, response) {
    var body = _.pick(request.body, 'full_name', 'email', 'password', 'repeat_password');

    body.rank = 0;

    body.full_name = body.full_name || '';
    body.email = body.email || '';
    body.password = body.password || '';
    body.repeat_password = body.repeat_password || '';

    var errors = {
        errors: [

        ]
    };

    if (body.full_name.length === 0) {
        errors.errors.push({
            message: 'The full name field cannot be empty.',
            path: 'full_name'
        });
    }

    if (body.email.length === 0) {
        errors.errors.push({
            message: 'The email field cannot be empty.',
            path: 'email'
        });
    }

    if (body.password.length === 0) {
        errors.errors.push({
            message: 'The password field cannot be empty.',
            path: 'password'
        });
    }

    if (body.repeat_password.length === 0) {
        errors.errors.push({
            message: 'The repeat password field cannot be empty.',
            path: 'repeat_password'
        });
    }

    if (errors.errors.length > 0) {
        response.status(400).json(errors).send();
    } else {
        if (body.password === body.repeat_password) {
            delete body.repeat_password;

            database.users.create(body).then( function(data) {
                response.send('Successfully created!');
            }).catch( function (errors) {
                response.status(400).json(errors).send();
            });
        } else {
            var error = {
                errors: [
                    {
                        message: "Repeated password does not match the previous.",
                        path: "repeat_password"
                    }
                ]
            };
            response.status(400).json(error).send();
        }
    }
});
```

And the HTML code for this particular form:

```
        <h1 class="main-title animated zoomInUp">HassanAlthaf.com</h1>

        <form novalidate class="index-form animated slideInLeft" data-ng-submit="submit()">
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.full_name" placeholder="Your full name">
            <p class="error">{{errors['full_name']}}</p>
            <input type="text" data-ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Your email address">
            <p class="error">{{errors['email']}}</p>
            <input type="password" data-ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Choose a password">
            <p class="error">{{errors['password']}}</p>
            <input type="password" data-ng-model="user.repeat_password" placeholder="Repeat your password">
            <p class="error">{{errors['repeat_password']}}</p>
            <div class="row">
                <button type="submit" class="button-green">Register</button>
                <button type="button" class="button-red pull-right" data-ng-click="home()">Home</button>    
            </div>
        </form>
```

And, finally, the relevant CSS code:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100italic,100,400,700);

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #34495E;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main-title {
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
}

.index-form {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.index-form input, .index-form button {
    display: block;
}

.index-form input {
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #2E4153;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto !important;
}

.index-form input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #22303D;
}

.red-border {
    border: 2px solid #C0392B;
}

.index-form .row {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.index-form button {
    width: 45%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    outline: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    transition: 0.3s background, 0.3s color;
}

.button-green {
    border: 2px solid #27AE60;
    color: #27AE60;
}

.button-green:hover {
    background: #27AE60;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button-green:active {
    background: #219251;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #219251;
}

.button-red {
    border: 2px solid #C0392B;
    color: #C0392B;
}

.button-red:hover {
    background: #C0392B;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button-red:active {
    background: #A43125;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px solid #A43125;
}

.error {
    color: #C0392B;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Big tablet to 1200px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .index-form input, .index-form .row {
        width: 30%;
    }
}

/* Small tablet to big tablet: from 768px to 1023px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {
    .index-form input, .index-form .row {
        width: 40%;
    }
}

/* Small phones to small tablets: from 481px to 767px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .index-form input, .index-form .row {
        width: 90%;
    }
}

/* Small phones: from 0 to 480px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .index-form input, .index-form .row {
        width: 90%;
    }
```

This behaviour is quite weird, and I would highly appreciate any sort of help. Well explained answers will receive a bounty from me.

Comment: Any errors in browser's console?

Comment: Yes, there is an error, because, I am developing a RESTful API. It returns an error 400 when invalid data is passed, with JSON strings.

Comment: Ah, the mystery fields UI design.

Comment: @epascarello What? :P

Comment: Btw, this is a `Single Page Application` using AngularJS. Therefore, during submission, the page does not reload.

Comment: Wrap the inputs/error message in a div with the class of row and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: @epascarello What do you mean? Each input and each error message with the class row?

Comment: Nevermind.... You are not using a framework like bootstrap. I see your .row does not match what row normally means.

Comment: @epascarello I am using Bootstrap.

Comment: Than why are you not using responsive grid for columns?

Comment: @epascarello I don't need columns. These are just rows. I like the placeholder style. :)

Comment: @epascarello Doing the row hack worked. But it squeezed my input field.

Comment: @epascarello Anyway, I am interested on learning what you just spoke about. Mind continuing about it on chat?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid and reason why it is crammed because you set widths on the inputs which will now size to the row height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @epascarello suggested, I simply wrapped each element inside: `<div class="row">....</div>`

This worked perfectly for me.